# How to select a filter a list of columns within a selection list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to be able to filter a DataFrame and keep the lines where a list of columns is in a selection list.

```
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5], 'C': range(4)})
```

Input:

```
df
   A  B  C
0  5  1  0
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
3  4  5  3

filter_list = [(6,2),(3,3)]
```

Expected result:

```
df
   A  B  C
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
```

I have tried with loc and map, but I don't manage to find a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague gave me a faster solution on big DataFrames by creating a filtering DataFrame:

```
from pandas import merge, DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5], 'C': range(4)})
filter_list = [(6,2),(3,3)]
filter_df = DataFrame(filter_list, columns=['A','B'])
filtr = merge(df, filter_df, on=["A","B"], how="inner")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
In [34]: df = DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4], 'B' : [1,2,3,5], 'C': range(4)})

In [35]: df
Out[35]: 
   A  B  C
0  5  1  0
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
3  4  5  3
```

Create a boolean indexer of the locations of the tuples, then select those rows from the frame

```
In [36]: df.loc[Series(zip(df.A,df.B)).isin([(6,2),(3,3)])]
Out[36]: 
   A  B  C
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
```

In 0.13 (releasing soon!), you can do this, [docs here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin)

```
In [37]: df.isin({ 'A' : [6,3], 'B' : [2,3] })
Out[37]: 
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1   True   True  False
2   True   True  False
3  False  False  False

In [38]: indexer = df.isin({ 'A' : [6,3], 'B' : [2,3] })

In [39]: indexer[['A','B']].all(1)
Out[39]: 
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
dtype: bool

In [40]: df.loc[indexer[['A','B']].all(1)]
Out[40]: 
   A  B  C
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
```

Comment: I was playing with this and also read [this post](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4576). Is it "normal" that you have to zip it into a series? Seems like there should be some way to compare directly on subsets of `df`.

Comment: yes, you are comparing tuples effectively because you want in A and in B, WHERE the ordering matters. Its not enought to say, for example, in A and in B

Comment: you will be able to do this in 0.13 with df.isin: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-with-isin

Comment: Cool about 0.13. I was thinking of tests like `df.loc[:,['A','B']] == (6,2)` or `df.loc[:,['A','B']].isin(filterlist)` Will read the docs.

Answer (score 2):

Use apply:

```
>>> fltr =  df.apply(lambda x: (x["A"], x["B"]) in {(6,2),(3,3)}, axis=1)
# 0    False
# 1     True
# 2     True
# 3    False
# dtype: bool
>>> df[fltr]
   A  B  C
1  6  2  1
2  3  3  2
```

Comment: Testing on my large DataFrame, Jeff's answer was faster.
Thanks anyway